# Rubyで平均値を算出するメソッドを簡潔に書きたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyで平均値を算出するメソッドを簡潔に書きたいです．
以下のサイトを参考にしたのですが，何故かうまくいきません
https://techacademy.jp/magazine/19683
ご教授よろしくお願いします．

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

class AAA
  def average
    self.inject(:+) / self.length    
  end
end

p "average = #{array.average}"
```

エラーメッセージは以下

```
undefined method `average' for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `class AAA`ではなく`class Array`ではないでしょうか

Comment: @orangecat 回答ありがとうございます．クラス名は必ず`Array`にしなければいけないのですか？

Comment: 既存の`Array`クラスに対してメソッドを追加したいのであれば、そうです。新しいクラスを作りたいのなら、お好きに。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たまに、今回のように、既存の組み込みクラスに対して、メソッドを生やしたくなる場合があります。しかし、組み込みクラスにメソッドを拡張した瞬間に、どこのライブラリが壊れるかわからない、という問題があります。

自分でしたら以下のようにして、 refinement を用いて読みやすくする、ことはあると思います。

```
module ArrayMixin
  refine Array do
    def average
      map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / length
    end
  end
end

class SomeCalculator
  using ArrayMixin

  def calculate(array)     
    avg = array.average
    puts avg

    # average を用いた処理を後続
  end
end

SomeCalculator.new.calculate([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: なるほど，丁寧な解説誠にありがとうございます．理解できた気がします．